# Tuleap document management : how to move a document with history across projects

Tags: documents

I have few projects in tuleap. I realized I have to move some document folders with documents from one project to other project keeping all the versions with history.
Can you please advice how to do that?
I tried cut-paste . It cuts the document from one project but in the next project I see the paste option is disabled.

regds
Sankar